# What would be some similar "-gang pairs"... to "Aufgang" and "Niedergang", as well as "Übergang" and "Untergang"?

Tags: word-choice, prefix

I'd like to frame this into a sort of fill-in-the-blank format, to best allude to the meanings I'm trying to ascribe to the above pairs. I will also, subsequently, put these pairs into a 3-axis matrix, to help discern what kind of "third pair" I'm trying to find; here is my query:

Where Aufgang and Niedergang are on a Y-Axis; and translate to rise and fall (roughly/creatively) into English, and Übergang and Untergang are on a Z-Axis; and translate to overcome and undergo (or, perhaps, more generically, as ascend and descend)..., ____-gang and ____-gang are on an X-axis, and translate to ____ and ____.

New edit (8/28):  The point was to find an xyz plane that utilized some of the provided, suggested translations, in order to determine how the xyz axis in english would [roughly] translate to:

X: ?? and ?? (A mortal-like quality, but similar words to the given pairs.)
Y: Rising and Falling (A divine/godly quality)
Z: Overcoming and Undergoing (A ethical/demigod-like quality)

Comment: Your suggested pairs are weird; while *Aufstieg* (instead of  Aufgang, which  is mostly used for  stairs and the sun) / *'Niedergang* is a valid counterpiece pair (but  *auf*/*ab* would be much more convincing). *Übergang* / *Untergang* is a mismatch similar to *transition* / *collapse*. On x-axis *left* / *right* is hard to avoid, as well as *vor* / *zurück*.

Comment: Something like _Eingang_ and _Ausgang_?

Comment: Or _Vorgang_ and _Nachgang_ or _Zugang_ and _Abgang_?

Comment: If you want to answer the questions in the comments, the way to do that without needing more reputation is by editing/clarifying the question itself. I know that it's frustrating how limited users are with low reputation on this site.

Comment: Clarifying the question by edit is the preferred way regardless of privileges. Otherwise one can get the situation where one does not understand an answer without reading the comments to the question.
Anyway, the good news is, once your reputation is above a certain level (not sure about the exact number), if you register for another SE site, you will not start with 1 there, but with 101.

Comment: Oh, and I have just approved your edit (not even sure why this was necessary) to not make your experience more Kafkaesque, but usually you wouldn't address individual people, but just make sure that your question as a whole makes sense. Also, thanking people does not really belong into questions.

Comment: The German translations of rise/fall, overcome/undergo,  ascend/descend are wrong in the question.

Comment: Your y-axis seems to be the height. But I don't get what you mean with z-axis and x-axis. Could you explain?

Comment: To me, it is unclear, what your question is. Is the aim to find pairs of words which describe a 3dim matrix or graph with high/low, left/right, up/down or are you looking for pairs which end in ~gang only? Note, that there is no language law, which says, if there is such a pair for auf and ab ("die Werte gehen auf und ab"), that there must be analog pairs for links/rechts or vorne/hinten. Additional difficulties arise, that expressions, which describe the y-axis in 2dim diagrams, can become ambiguous when used in 3D (hoch/tief for instance),

Comment: Even after the edit I'm not sure what you are asking. To me it seems your question needs considerable more context or focus to become understandable and answerable. Are you looking for pairs of opposite meaning?

Answer (score 2):

The pairs in your assumption are incorrect.

- **Aufgang**

  1. This is the movement of the sun, the moon, any Planet and any star from below the horizon to above the horizon. For the sun it's *sunrise* in English, and *moonrise* etc. The opposite word (sunset, moonset, ...) is **Untergang.**
  2. A second meaning is a stairway or a corridor with a slope that leads from a main level up to a higher level. The opposite word (stairway/corridor going down) is **Abgang.**
- **Niedergang**

  1. This is the process of collapsing or going under (*»der **Niedergang** des Römischen Reichs« = »the **decline** of the Roman Empire«*) The opposite word (the rise) is **Aufstieg** (no ...gang).
  2. A small staircase or ladder on ships to connect two decks. For this meaning there is no opposite word.
- **Übergang**

  1. This is the German word for a transition or change of a person or thing from one state into another (*»Der **Übergang** vom Mittelalter in die die Neuzeit ging mit großen gesellschaftlichen Veränderungen einher.« = »The **transition** from the Middle Ages to modern times was accompanied by great social changes.«*) - There is no opposite word for this meaning.
  2. An *Übergang* can also be a bridge. (*»Die beiden Zwillings-Bürotürme sind im 12. Stockwerk durch einen **Übergang** miteinander verbunden.« = »The two twin office towers are connected by a **passageway** on the 12th floor.«*) - Also this meaning doesn't have an opposite word.
- **Untergang**

  1. This is a synonym for Niedergang-1 (*»Der **Untergang** des Römischen Reichs« = »the **decline** of the Roman Empire«*) The opposite word (the rise) is **Aufstieg**.
  2. For sun, moon etc. this is the opposite word for Aufgang-1 (*»Sonnen**untergang**« = »sunset«*).

---

### some other frequently used nouns ending in *...gang*

- **Zugang** = access, entrance
- **Jahrgang** = age group, cohort
- **Umgang** = contact, handling, exposure
- **Vorgang** = procedure, process
- **Ausgang** = exit, outcome
- **Eingang** = entrance, access, inlet
- **Durchgang** = pass, passage, transit
- **Rückgang** = reduction, decline, decrease
- **Alleingang** = solo effort, solo
- **Abgang** = loss, separation, outflow
- **Tiefgang** = flotation depth, draft, gauge
- **Hergang** = course of events
- **Hauptgang** = main course, main corridor, master lode
- **Freigang** = prison leave, free access, ease of operation

There are many hundreds of such nouns (*Müßiggang, Kirchgang, Heimgang, Wellengang, Rückwärtsgang, Gehörgang, Landgang, Stuhlgang, Seegang, Nachgang, Hofgang, Krebsgang, Bittgang* and much much more with extremely different meanings.)

Comment: +1 Good answer. I just want to add the opposite of Übergang=passageway is Unterführung=underbridge. The opposite to "small staircase" is "Aufgang".